# Email validation through csv file not working

Tags: php, validation, foreach, mailgun

I am using mailgun api to validate email addresses from a csv file. If the file holds 30-40 records then it works fine but as soon as I pass bigger file with almost 1000 records it doesn't work. I have increased max_execution_time still no effect. any help would be great

here is my code

```
$file = fopen($target_file, 'r');
$counter=0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
if($counter!=0){
 foreach($line as $key=>$value){
         if($key == 4){
             # Issue the call to the client.
            $result = $mgClient->get("address/validate", array('address' => $value,'mailbox_verification'=>true));
            # is_valid is 0 or 1
            $isValid = $result->http_response_body->is_valid;       
            if($isValid==1){
                     echo $value."<br/>";
            }
         }

 }
}
$counter++;

}
fclose($file);
```

Ps: this loop is working for 30-40 record file but not for bigger file

Comment: adding `sleep(1);` after one call would be helpful too, add it before ending foreach

Comment: This is what databases are made for...

Comment: What is the http response body after processing of 40 records?

Comment: Now it is throwing me this error  Fatal error: Uncaught Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\GenericHTTPError: An HTTP Error has occurred! Check your network connection and try again. I am so dead . Have tried new install and everything but nothing